# Should a resource have multiple routes?

Tags: api, rest, express

I am building an application were we have two types of user:

- Admin
- Regular user

The admin will have access to all resources inside the application.
The manager will control the resources only inside its project.

If inside a project we have some resources as for example "Items". The manager should be able to see all the items inside the project. My planned route for that resource is this one:

- localhost:3000/api/project/1/items

But the admin will also be able to see and modify any Item, so probably he will need something like this to see all the items.

- localhost:3000/api/items

I am a little confuse since having multiple routes for the same resource seems a little bit bad.

I will be glad to hear opinions or other proposals.

Comment: It's not clear why you think you need separate URLs for the same resource or where this would be happening.  It's perfectly fine if `http://localhost:3000/api/project/1/items` represents all of a project's items and `http://localhost:3000/api/items` represents all items regardless of project.  These are different collections of resources so OK to have different URLs for the different collections.  Now, when referencing a given item, no matter which collection it was accessed from should probably have the same URL when accessing just that item.

Comment: It is not the same resource. I know you think it is but it is not. They are two very different lists. One is a list of items in a project. The other is a list of all items. "all" and "project" are different resources. Look at it this way. Chad is a waiter working at a diner. Chat is also a promising young actor. You may think that Chad is the same person but if I were to ask for a list of all waiters working in diners and all actors in Hollywood I'm asking for two different things even though both lists contain Chad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources, in the context of REST, are the things identified by uniform resource identifiers.  So you are never going to have the "same" resource with two different identifiers  (see Fielding, 2000 or [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-resources)).

You can have two different resources that have the same [representation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-representations), or a single resource that has multiple distinct representations (a simple example being a single "web page" with representations in multiple languages).

REST, of itself, doesn't actually place any constraints on what your resources *should be*.  All of the general purpose components shared in the world are going to assume that distinct identifiers mean distinct resources, and that the messages we use targeting resources all mean the same thing, as is true of the metadata that we use to describe representations.

But it isn't going to say that you should have one resource, or two resources, or three resources.  And it isn't going to tell you what spelling conventions you use for the identifiers.

For a lot of concerns, it will be *easier* if you choose a model where the two different views of the information are distinct (for example, it allows an auditor to easily compare the public and restricted documents side by side to look for errors; the distinct resources appear differently in browser history, you can pass resource identifiers around without ambiguity, and so on).

But if the things made easier by creating separate resources are not valuable in your context, and combining the two different views as distinct representations of the same resource is valuable, then it can be reasonable to create a single resource.

(For example; if you are dealing with resources that are only accessible via authorized requests, then the calculus of caching changes quite a bit -- see [RFC 9111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-storing-responses-to-authen)).